# HTML Links Not Working - Is this a div issue?

Tags: html, css

Please forgive me if I am completely missing something here. I am somewhat of a newbie.

I have two links in the footer of my webpage that aren't linking. I checked the  tags many times and it appears to be correct. Could this be a div issue? I was thinking there was a  that might be layered above it that is blocking the user from the link.

The dead links located [here](http://crystalcoveadvisors.com/) in the footer, second column under MORE INFORMATION. The links are blue.

Comment: Please post your relevant `HTML` (the HTML of your 'dead' links) and expceted results, links to images or other sites and images are discouraged.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself as an [mcve]. Stack Overflow is about helping everyone with a similar question that finds the issue via search. Thus, if they come to this question once you've fixed the issue, that link isn't going to help illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add `position: relative` to your `footer-wrapper` class.**

The links are not actually dead - they are correctly created and have valid links, they are simply unclickable because the footer is unclickable.

Adding the css style mentioned above fixes this issue while letting you retain all of your styling.

Comment: Great! Happy to help. If this was the solution you went with, please mark this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `<div class="push"></div>` from your `<div class="wrapper"></div>`
2. `.footer-wrapper{ margin-top: 560px; }` at line 2633 in your style.css file

Try to do it

Comment: and you can click to FINRA / SIPC  links :)